# Disable the default tick to send email confirmation for events registration.

Tags: civievent

Do you know of a way to disable the check box for send email confirmation when registering a participant to an event manually from the back office? Even when the event settings say no automated email confirmation when you try to register a participant manually you get the tick box for send email confirmation enabled.

Please help if you know a method to disable this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extension which does that here: [Prevent Sending Event Registration Confirmation from the Back-Office](https://civicrm.org/extensions/prevent-sending-event-registration-confirmation-back-office)